# setOverlayImage error in fabricJS canvas - bug?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm having an problem where every time the mouse is clicked and dragged to select a section of the canvas a large amount of the same error will appear. I've stripped my code down to the bare minimum to make this error happen:

`var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('card_canvas');
canvas.setOverlayImage('/man/images/card_overlay.png',canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));`

This error can also be seen on the setOverlayImage demo on the fabricJS website, the error is:

`TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.`

From what i understand this is due to setOverlayImage using a url string instead of an image object, however if i pass an image object through it won't work at all. How would i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted seem to [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/eqmwqnch/1/), this jsfiddle use the latest version of the library from the github repository, maybe the bug was fixed then.

Alternative :

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('/man/images/card_overlay.png', function(img) {
    canvas.setOverlayImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
});
```

Comment: The problem was with build 1.4.0, thank you for figuring this  out